# bash to choose different first argument file and process everyday

Tags: bash, ping

I'm running a ping test, and placing list of IP's as first argument in a text file. So everyday the list keeps changing and that's managed by other script and creates files everyday as follows

```
test-apr1.txt
test-apr2.txt
test-apr3.txt
```

Here what I'm really looking is that my shell/bash script should choose these files as first argument daily

For eg:-
I'm starting script using below

```
./ping.sh test-apr1.txt &  { first day }
./ping.sh test-apr2.txt &  { second day }
```

Here on second day the script should choose the newly created file at 12:AM on 2nd April.

Likewise how to tell bash to behave like this. Or do I need to run a another shell script to manage this one "ping.sh"

Please shadow some ideas...

Answer (score 2):

You probably want

```
file_for_today=$( date "+test_%b%e.txt" | sed 's/ //' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' )
./ping.sh "$file_for_today"
```

Comment: it seems to me that it must be ` date "+test-...` instead ` date "+test_...`

Comment: if necessary to fix the month in English (format, parameter% b):   
`$( LC_ALL=C date "+test-%b%e.txt" ...)`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
./ping.sh "test-apr$(( 1 + $(date +%s)/3600/24 % 3 )).txt"
```

#### How it works

`$(date +%s)` is the number of seconds since epoch.  `$(date +%s)/3600/24` is the number of days since epoch.  `$(date +%s)/3600/24 % 3` is the number of days since epoch modulo 3.  This will rotate through the numbers 0, 1, and 2.  Since you want to rotate through 1, 2, and 3, we add one to this:

```
1 + $(date +%s)/3600/24 % 3
```

As I write, this happens to evaluate to `3`:

```
$ echo $(( 1 + $(date +%s)/3600/24 % 3 ))
3
```

Tomorrow at this time, it will evaluate to `1`.  The day after, it will evaluate to `2`.  And then, the pattern will repeat.